# Proper typing for Array.flat(Infinity)

Tags: typescript, flatten

I learned about the new [`Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method and thought I'd use it to try it out but the returned type isn't desired.

```
const hello = [1, 2, [3], [[4]]]

const x = hello.flat(Infinity)
```

This sets `x`'s type as:

```
const x: (number | number[] | number[][])[]
```

How can I have this so that it's `number[]`?

Comment: Are you using TS3.9 beta or something?  I can't reproduce on 3.8.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you must be using the beta version of TypeScript 3.9 with the [new typings for `Array.flat()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32131).  The main problem here is that TypeScript does not currently have a [numeric literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types) corresponding to `Infinity` (see [microsoft/TypeScript#32277](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32277)
 for an open suggestion to add this).

Right now, the type of `Infinity` in TypeScript is just `number`.  So the compiler has no idea that `array.flat(Infinity)` is going to return the most-flat-possible array; instead it treats it as if you've called `array.flat(num)` where `num` is some `number`-valued expression.  Meaning it has no idea how flat the final array will be and ends up giving you a union of all kinds of possible flattening depths:

```
const z = [[[[[[0 as const]]]]]].flat(Infinity);
// const z: (0 | 0[] | 0[][] | 0[][][] | 0[][][][] | 0[][][][][])[]
```

This issue with `flat()` is noted in [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36554#issuecomment-605087265) under [microsoft/TypeScript#36554](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36554), an issue that acts as a collection of use cases for array methods that don't act perfectly in TypeScript at the moment.  If you really care about this you might want to give it a  so that people know the use case is in use.

---

I'd suggest for the time being that you should just pass in a large-ish numeric constant whose type can be represented as a numeric literal.  The new typings are only accurate up to a depth of about `20` or so, so you might as well pick something like that:

```
const y = [[[[[[0 as const]]]]]].flat(20);
// const y: 0[]

const x = hello.flat(20); // number[]
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNgQ2AQQE6oSAPG1AaKAEQjGAAsoIAPYCAOwBMBnKOgVwFsAjCVAPigBeKAG8AsACgo0qACIGAezoRZALii48kmXNQQAxm1RqN6SjXrMoAJQgJFdOCFyYsASzoAzXlACSdZVRcPm0ZAH5YRBR0V39AzSgAbQBaAEYCAAYCdKgAJgIAZgIAFgIAVgIANgIAdgIADgIATmysqFSc1Pz2ovbS9or26va69sb2lryMgF1E4lIyaZCpGXVcSQBfOZJyc1pGFjSoCPklFSh1WT1DY2mAbklHiQ9aVE8EfWgXbAAVAXEVtJPFEcARCHtLCx2NwfMJUnwABShHTSchuJhrLSAlEMHZkMLqQjIqAASnU8CQ31BRD4iXumyekn0SiYwCgZAgcDgCiESRy3USBWmBESiWK0wlT2ZdFZUAAXrzRUrEhkoAgWNLWRLtdMAHTApAI-yeDxuUAkh4SAD0VqgmrZcvUCNVAB8oBk6VA3R7ZtMve66YG-d6g0H-T7Q76SXSpSy2SBFcqVWqNXGdRL9VEEbkMhbJDa7XGoCB1D7YzK2VReRyuQpM4acxaoAXoTxUDGJJIgA)

Comment: Very ugly but correct at runtime: `hello.flat(<20>Infinity)`